# AngularJS - Referring to a $scope name/ng-model that has '.' in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having trouble using an ng-model in a filter function.
The input is currently named "search.anything". I can't change the name as it will effect other filters.

I want to use it as a parameter in a filter function. Is there any other way I can enter the value?
**$scope.search.anything** is definitely wrong.

```
$scope.myFilter = function(course) {
  var isMatch = false;

  if ($scope.search.anything) {
    var parts = $scope.search.anything.split(' ');

    parts.forEach(function(part) {
      if (new RegExp(part).test(course.keywords)) {
        isMatch = true;
      }
    });
  } else {
    isMatch = true;
  }

  return isMatch;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Demo:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello World!";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Message: {{message}}</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have added a snippet in your post. Please updated it with minimal code to show your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `md-input-container` ([ref](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInputContainer)) to input the filter value (here I use an `input`, but you could use an `md-select` or any other input method. In the `ng-repeat` you could use a custom filter (`filter: functionFilter`, [ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)).

To handle the "." inside the property name you could save it in a variable`ctrl.searchKey = "search.anything";` and any time you want to acces it in JS `ctrl[ctrl.searchKey] = "value1";` and in HTML you could also use a string literal `"ctrl['search.anything']"`.

If you change the "Filter value" to "value2" or "value3" it will filter the `ng-repeat`.

Here is a code snippet example. Hope this helps.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  const ctrl = this;
  ctrl.data = [{
    value: "value1"
  }, {
    value: "value2"
  }, {
    value: "value3"
  }];
  ctrl.searchKey = "search.anything";
  ctrl[ctrl.searchKey] = "value1";
  ctrl.myFilter = input => input.value === ctrl[ctrl.searchKey];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Filter value</label>
      <input ng-model="ctrl['search.anything']">
    </md-input-container>
    <div ng-repeat="entity in ctrl.data | filter: ctrl.myFilter"> Value filtered {{ entity.value }}</div>
  </div>
</section>
```